# vb6: redimensioning of 2D dynamic array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, vb6, dynamic-arrays

I am using arrays to store properties of steam according to it's pressure. Right now I have properties of exactly 9 pressures so I'm using static array. I'd like to be more flexible so I'd like to switch to dynamic arrays.

When I use `ReDim foo(1 to i, 1 to 10)` in loop I completely loose all data except last line.
When I use `ReDim Preserve foo(1 to i, 1 to 10)` or `ReDim Preserve(i,10)` Program throws error of *"Runtime error '9': subscript out of range"*. `i` goes from 1 to 9.

How can I add line/column to array full of data without loosing them?

Comment: Why are your arrays 2D? Storing properties of steam vs pressure sounds like several 1D arrays, or possibly a single 1D array of user-defined types or classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may only Redim Preserve the *final* dimension in a VB6 multidimensional array. Here's the info from MSDN:

> If you include the Preserve keyword,
>   Visual Basic copies the elements from
>   the existing array to the new array.
>   When you use Preserve, you can resize
>   only the last dimension of the array,
>   and for every other dimension you must
>   specify the same size it already has
>   in the existing array.
>
> For example, if your array has only
>   one dimension, you can resize that
>   dimension and still preserve the
>   contents of the array, because it is
>   the last and only dimension. However,
>   if your array has two or more
>   dimensions, you can change the size of
>   only the last dimension if you use
>   Preserve.
>
> The following example increases the
>   size of the last dimension of a
>   dynamic array without losing any
>   existing data in the array, and then
>   decreases the size with partial data
>   loss:

```
 Dim IntArray(10, 10, 10) As Integer 
 ReDim Preserve IntArray(10, 10, 20) 
 ReDim Preserve IntArray(10, 10, 15)
```

Comment: So `ReDim Preserve IntArray(20, 10, 10)` will fail and only `ReDim Preserve IntArray(10, 10, 20)` will work, right?

Comment: Thanks. I have to bend different branch :)

Comment: +1 here is a link to the MSDN doc quoted http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266231(v=VS.60).aspx